# Trace Python imports

Tags: python, debugging, import, trace

My Python library just changed it's main module name from `foo.bar` to `foobar`. For backward compat, `foo.bar` still exists, but importing it raises a few warnings. Now, it seems some example program still imports from the old module, but not directly.

I'd like to find the erroneous `import` statement. Is there any tool that allows me to trace imports and find the culprit without wading through all of the code?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Start the python interpreter with `-v`:

```
$ python -v -m /usr/lib/python2.6/timeit.py
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# /usr/lib/python2.6/site.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.6/site.py
import site # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.6/site.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.6/os.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.6/os.py
import os # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.6/os.pyc
import errno # builtin
import posix # builtin
# /usr/lib/python2.6/posixpath.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.6/posixpath.py
import posixpath # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.6/posixpath.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.6/stat.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.6/stat.py
import stat # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.6/stat.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.6/genericpath.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.6/genericpath.py
import genericpath # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.6/genericpath.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.6/warnings.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.6/warnings.py
import warnings # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.6/warnings.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.6/linecache.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.6/linecache.py
import linecache # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.6/linecache.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.6/types.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.6/types.py
import types # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.6/types.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.6/UserDict.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.6/UserDict.py
...
```

Then just grep for your old module.

Comment: Also, if you don't have access to the Python command line (e.g., the interpreter is embedded), then you can set PYTHONVERBOSE to 1 in the environment to get the same effect.

Comment: This is a *really* useful trick. Often times imports work fine in a shell and blow up in a server setup where the paths are different. Using this trick with PYTHONVERBOSE is a lifesaver when you're not in a Python shell.

Comment: By the way, higher values of `PYTHONVERBOSE` give more info. If 1 only tells where things were picked from, a higher number will result in messages showing what paths were tried. Helps a lot when figuring out why a package was not found.

Comment: This does not provide a stack trace for imports.  Which file called `import site`?  Was it `timeit.py`?  Or was it `zipimport`?  In a much more complicated environment I need to know the trace, but cannot find one.

Answer (score 8):

edit foo.bar module, add following code:

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

when foo.bar be imported, program will stop at pdb.set_trace() in pdb mode, where you can debug your code. For example, you can use "w" command to print the full calling stack.

Answer (score 1):

I will first introduce the general solution and then show how it can be adapted for this particular use case.

#### General solution

Nowadays there are easier ways to debug such things utilizing the new functionalities of the python import system. Basically just add your own module finders (MetaPathFinder) to **[`sys.meta_path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.meta_path)**. Here is an example  for a script importing `pandas` and listing all the succesful imports in `imported` and unsuccesful imports in `could_not_be_imported`:

```py
import sys

imported = []
could_not_be_imported = []


class FirstFinder:
    def find_spec(self, modulename, path=None, target=None):
        imported.append(modulename)


class LastFinder:
    def find_spec(self, modulename, path=None, target=None):
        imported.remove(modulename)
        could_not_be_imported.append(modulename)

# setup ("start recording imports")
sys.meta_path.insert(0, FirstFinder())
sys.meta_path.append(LastFinder())

import pandas # import anything here 

# cleanup ("stop recording")
sys.meta_path = [
    x for x in sys.meta_path if not isinstance(x, (FirstFinder, LastFinder))
]
```

The list containing the succesful imports is then **`imported`**:

```
>>> imported
['pandas',
 'numpy',
 'numpy._globals',
 # ...
 'pandas.io.sql',
 'pandas.io.stata',
 'pandas.io.xml',
 'pandas.util._tester',
 'pandas._version']
```

and **`could_not_be_imported`**:

```py
>>> could_not_be_imported 
['pickle5',
 'org',
 'fcntl',
 'backports_abc',
 'six.moves',
 'backports_abc',
 'backports_abc',
 # ...
 'cloudpickle',
 'numexpr',
 'bottleneck',
 'org',
 'backports_abc',
 'backports_abc',
 'backports_abc']
```

**Note**: There can be duplicates in either of the lists and all the modules are listed in order of imports. Modify as fits to your needs.

#### Specific use case: Finding Erroneous import

Modify the `LastFinder` to be:

```py
class LastFinder:
    def find_spec(self, modulename, path=None, target=None):
        imported.remove(modulename)
        print(
            "\nMissing module! ",
            f"Tried to import: {modulename}\n",
            "Last few last imports:\n\t",
            "\n\t ".join(imported[-10:]),
        )
        could_not_be_imported.append(modulename)
```

This will then print, with every missing module, a list of the few last succesfully imported modules and the module you were trying to import. For example:

```
Missing module!  Tried to import: bottleneck
 Last few last imports:
         pandas.core.ops.common
         pandas.core.ops.docstrings
         pandas.core.ops.mask_ops
         pandas.core.ops.methods
         pandas.core.missing
         pandas.core.array_algos.quantile
         pandas.core.sorting
         pandas.core.arrays.boolean
         pandas.core.arrays.masked
         pandas.core.nanops
```

In this case this would mean that the `pandas.core.nanops` was the last succcesful import before the unsuccesful import. Therefore, it would be quite easy to check from `pandas.core.nanops.__file__` where the broken import is. (look for `"bottleneck"` in the file). In my case, I found:

```
# pandas\core\nanops.py
# ...
bn = import_optional_dependency("bottleneck", errors="warn")
```

#### How this works?

The python import system goes through the `sys.meta_path` to look for a spec finder which will have `find_spec` method which returns something else than `None`. If `None` is returned, next finder in `sys.meta_path` is used for the import.