# what is the correct import query for pocketsphinx ?

Tags: python, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I cant use pocketsphinx api
while compiling decoder_test.py:

```
from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
ImportError: No module named pocketsphinx
```

I have installed pocketsphinx and sphinxbase correctly as mentioned in documentation 
`import pocketsphinx` works perfectly. 
But while calling `Decoder` function getting error as `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Decoder'`

Comment: It's hard to help because there's no information about what _documentation_ you've read as well as about the installation method.

Comment: it was my problem, and i were installed old pocketsphinx and used new object calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug imports you can start python with -v: `python -v`, then type required import. You should see the following:

```
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
dlopen("/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so", 2);
import readline # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so
>>> from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
import pocketsphinx # directory /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx
# /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx/__init__.pyc matches /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx/__init__.py
import pocketsphinx # precompiled from /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx/__init__.pyc
# /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx/pocketsphinx.pyc matches /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx/pocketsphinx.py
import pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx # precompiled from /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx/pocketsphinx.pyc
import imp # builtin
dlopen("/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx/_pocketsphinx.so", 2);
import _pocketsphinx # dynamically loaded from /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx/_pocketsphinx.so
import sphinxbase # directory /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sphinxbase
# /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sphinxbase/__init__.pyc matches /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sphinxbase/__init__.py
import sphinxbase # precompiled from /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sphinxbase/__init__.pyc
# /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sphinxbase/sphinxbase.pyc matches /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sphinxbase/sphinxbase.py
import sphinxbase.sphinxbase # precompiled from /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sphinxbase/sphinxbase.pyc
dlopen("/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sphinxbase/_sphinxbase.so", 2);
import _sphinxbase # dynamically loaded from /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sphinxbase/_sphinxbase.so
```

See for more details [Trace Python imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332299/trace-python-imports)

In case you see something different, you have older installation of pocketsphinx, you didn't configure python loading path or you didn't install pocketsphinx properly.