# How to uninstall TensorFlow completely?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, tensorflow

I accidentally installed TensorFlow for Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled. When I installed with Linux 64-bit CPU only, I am getting Segmentation fault while importing tensorflow from python console.[image]

Answer (score 2):

First try `python -v -c "import tensorflow"` to find out the place of the module file. Delete any `tensorflow.so` or similar files.

Possible paths include $PYTHONPATH, `prefix/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, `exec-prefix/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and `$HOME/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Run `python -c "print sys.path"` to get a full list of paths.

Comment: do you mean `python2.7/dist-packages/` ??

Comment: The easiest way is to search for any file with "tensorflow" in the name under your python installation folder. If you are not sure, run `python -c "print sys.path"` to see.

Comment: the directory `site-packages` is empty. :(

Comment: Please check the updated answer and this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332299/trace-python-imports)

Answer (score 0):

After removing all the files associated with tensorflow-gpu, go to the File-Settings-Project:PycharmProjects-Project Interpreter. Look for any package related to tensorflow-gpu and remove that.

Answer (score 0):

From the tensor flow website.
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux

Do the following for uninstallation:

Uninstalling TensorFlow

To uninstall TensorFlow, simply remove the tree you created. For example:

$ rm -r targetDirectory