# Remove all traces of tensorflow-gpu installation on Win10

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, gpu

I'm having an issue reverting to tensorflow-cpu from gpu on Windows 10 64 bit, Python 3.5.3.

I'm using [riga/tfdeploy](https://github.com/riga/tfdeploy) to distribute trained models, which is not compatible with tf-gpu. I installed tf-gpu for an experiment, then reverted to cpu, all using pip install/uninstall. Now I'm getting error messages about unknown ops like **RealDiv** and **VariableV2**. When starting a tensorflow session I now get a bunch of messages that did not appear before installing and uninstalling the GPU version, like:

`OpKernel ('op: "BestSplits" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits`

My question is: How can I remove any trace of tf-gpu from my system and get back to tf-cpu? I'm using tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl (V1.0.0)

I read this:

[How to uninstall TensorFlow completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36902457/how-to-uninstall-tensorflow-completely)

And several related issues on GitHub, but haven't been able to go back to tf-cpu.

Steps to reproduce:

1. On Win 10 64 bit, Python 3.5.3, pip install tensorflow
2. run a tf.Session() - no messages about ops like BestSplits, RealDiv etc., tfdeploy runs fine.
3. pip install tensorflow-gpu
4. pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
5. Some trace of these ops remains registered, causing warnings like `OpKernel ('op: "BestSplits" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits` while runninng tf, and also causing frameworks like tfdeploy to crash

I have tried completely reinstalling Python 3, deleting all site-packages etc. I've installed and uninstalled CUDA. The ops seem to be registered somewhere, leading to different behavior of tf-cpu after installing and uninstalling tf-gpu.

Any pointers on getting rid of/unregistering these ops is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug on the PYPI packages generating OpKernel errors. The fix for that as of now is to uninstall TensorFlow, download a [nightly build](http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-win/97/) and install it, while the PYPI packages are not replaced.

Please see [this issue on Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7500#issuecomment-280194967) for more details.

Comment: OK, thanks, this is helpful! I installed the CPU version under the nightly build link (Feb 27), and now the OpKernel issue is solved (except for a warning about SSE instructions, which I assume wants me to build from source).

The other problem still remains: tfdeploy fails on an unknown op RealDiv. Do I need an older version of tensorflow? The latest release of https://github.com/riga/tfdeploy is Dec 23. Thanks for your help!

Comment: OK, I was able to revert to tf 0.12.0 and everything works, it seems tfdeploy is not up to date. Thanks!