# Import working in console but not in pyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I had a python project with a lot of imports like:

```
from src.main.fr.some.module import someclass
```

and it was working good but my colleagues wanted the imports to be like:

```
from fr.some.module import someclass
```

Then I changed the `PYTHONPATH` in the `activate` script of my `virtualenv` like:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main:/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/test"
```

and replaced all the `src.main.fr.some.module` with `fr.some.module`.

Then I tried my code in the console and the output was good (note that I am printing the `PYTHONPATH` at the beginning of my code and `/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main` appears like expected).

```
(WopMars)giffon@CZC0507G5C-HP-Z400:~/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/tagc/wopmars/framework/parsing$ python3 Parser.py 
PRINTING THE PYTHONPATH
/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/tagc/wopmars/framework/parsing
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyparsing-2.1.4-py3.4.egg
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cycler-0.10.0-py3.4.egg
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pytz-2016.4-py3.4.egg
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.5.3-py3.4.egg
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py3.4.egg
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy-1.11.0-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg
/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main
/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/test
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python3.4
/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4/site-packages



Reading the definition file... -> done.
Checking whether the file is well formed... -> done.
Building the execution DAG... -> done.
Writing the dot file... -> done.
```

But, since I am working with pycharm, I wanted the IDE to take my changes into account. And here comes the issues.

I read somewhere that I should modify the interpreter Python Path by doing the following:

> File > Settings > Projet:wopmars > Projet Interpreter > "wheel" >
>   More... > "Show path for the selected interpreter (WopMars interpreter
>   selected)" > + > "Browse to /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main" >
>   Ok > Ok > Apply > Ok

And then I execute the same code than above:

```
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/bin/python3 /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/tagc/wopmars/framework/parsing/Parser.py
PRINTING THE PYTHONPATH
/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/tagc/wopmars/framework/parsing
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyparsing-2.1.4-py3.4.egg
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cycler-0.10.0-py3.4.egg
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pytz-2016.4-py3.4.egg
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.5.3-py3.4.egg
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py3.4.egg
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy-1.11.0-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg
/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/test
/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python3.4
/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/home/giffon/virtualenvs/WopMars/lib/python3.4/site-packages



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/tagc/wopmars/framework/parsing/Parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from fr.tagc.wopmars.framework.management.DAG import DAG
ImportError: No module named 'fr.tagc.wopmars.framework.management.DAG'
```

You probably noticed that the `/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main` appears in the `PYTHONPATH` meaning that the configuration of pycharm
interpreter's path has been taken into account. So, the interpreter knows where to find modules but can't see `fr`... any idea for solving this issue?

It is probably not interesting for solving this issue but the error-raising code is:

```
print("PRINTING THE PYTHONPATH")                          
for p in sys.path:                                        
    print(p)                                              
print("\n\n")                                             


from fr.tagc.wopmars.framework.management.DAG import DAG
```

*Note: changing `PYTHONPATH` in `.profile` or `.bashrc` gave me the same results*

*Note2: if I don't export PYTHONPATH, the console give me the same error than pycharm*

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7334681/620382

Comment: Thanks a lot, I figured my problem and answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue thanks to Zulan's comment.

**TLDR:**

Put the `src/main/` directory before `src/test/` one in pycharm interpreter `PYTHONPATH`.

---

Using the -v option for python interpreter in both pycharm and console, I have got the following outputs:

Console output:

```
# /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc matches /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/__init__.py
# code object from '/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc'
import 'fr' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f384ce4b160>
# /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/tagc/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc matches /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/tagc/__init__.py
# code object from '/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/tagc/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc'
import 'fr.tagc' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f384ce4b358>
# /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/tagc/wopmars/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc matches /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/tagc/wopmars/__init__.py
# code object from '/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/tagc/wopmars/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc'
import 'fr.tagc.wopmars' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f384ce4b400>
# /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/tagc/wopmars/framework/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc matches /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/tagc/wopmars/framework/__init__.py
# code object from '/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/tagc/wopmars/framework/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc'
import 'fr.tagc.wopmars.framework' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f384ce4b4a8>
# /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/tagc/wopmars/framework/management/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc matches /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/tagc/wopmars/framework/management/__init__.py
# code object from '/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/tagc/wopmars/framework/management/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc'
import 'fr.tagc.wopmars.framework.management' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f384ce4b550>
```

Pycharm output:

```
# /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/test/fr/tagc/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc matches /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/test/fr/tagc/__init__.py
# code object from '/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/test/fr/tagc/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc'
import 'fr.tagc' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fb1532422e8>
# /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/test/fr/tagc/wopmars/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc matches /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/test/fr/tagc/wopmars/__init__.py
# code object from '/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/test/fr/tagc/wopmars/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc'
import 'fr.tagc.wopmars' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fb153242390>
# /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/test/fr/tagc/wopmars/framework/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc matches /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/test/fr/tagc/wopmars/framework/__init__.py
# code object from '/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/test/fr/tagc/wopmars/framework/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc'
import 'fr.tagc.wopmars.framework' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fb153242438>
# /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/test/fr/tagc/wopmars/framework/management/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc matches /home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/test/fr/tagc/wopmars/framework/management/__init__.py
# code object from '/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/test/fr/tagc/wopmars/framework/management/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc'
import 'fr.tagc.wopmars.framework.management' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fb1532424e0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main/fr/tagc/wopmars/framework/parsing/Parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from fr.tagc.wopmars.framework.management.DAG import DAG
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'fr.tagc.wopmars.framework.management.DAG'
```

You may have noticed the slight difference between the two output: console interpreter search in `wopmars/src/main/` whereas pycharm interpreter search in `wopmars/src/test/`.

Actually, if I look carefully at the printed `PYTHONPATH`, they are not the same:

- In the console, `/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main` appears before `/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/test`  in the list `sys.path`
- In Pycharm, it's the opposite

Then, I put `/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/test` **after** `/home/giffon/Documents/wopmars/src/main` in pycharm and it worked perfectly. I Think that python interpreter start finding the first part of the module name in `src/test/` then he don't find the end and raise an error without looking in other paths.