# how can I find the line of code where a module is being imported

Tags: python, python-2.7

Somewhere in my library code I have a `matplotlib.pyplot` import.  When I import one of my library modules I see that pyplot ends up getting imported (as evidenced by the fact that, in ipython notebook, my notebook immediately crashes because I did not run %matplotlib inline).

How can I get a stacktrace showing the sequence of imports (starting with my library module import) that resulted in pyplot getting imported?  So far I have tried using sed to replace all my instances of

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

to

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace(); from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

but that hasn't turned it up yet.

Comment: Why can't you do a recursive word search for pyplot through that library?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: You state "Somewhere in my library code I have a matplotlib.pyplot import". Why can't you search for where that happens?

Comment: Sorry, that was confusing. I have a bunch of pyplot imports in my library, and one of them is getting hit from importing one of my modules (which does not directly import pyplot but which imports other modules which import other modules which... eventually imports pyplot). I want to know how to find the path that led to the pyplot import so I can reorganize my library structure.

Comment: Sorry, it's still confusing: I would think things start with a script, or perhaps a one-liner in the console (Jupyter or default). That scripts imports what? The library, or a module? If it imports a module, does that module (indirectly) import the library? Is it the *library* where the (bad) pyplot import happens (yes, as I read it now, but just want to double check)?

Comment: I'm also surprised that just a pyplot import crashes your notebook (I can do `from matplotlib import pyplot` in a notebook just fine, without any extras). I assume then that there's no traceback (not on the command line running the notebook either), but a segfault or similar?

Comment: I wonder if you can install matplotlib locally (eg, with `--user` or `--prefix`), set that first in your PYTHONPATH, and raise an exception at the top of the `pyplot.py` module (or if you have access and don't mind meddling in the default installation, you could do it directly there). The exception should provide you with a traceback of the import sequence (just don't use `raise SystemExit()`: that exception won't show a traceback).

Comment: Not sure what you mean with comment #4.  In a script (or in ipython notebook, which is basically a script) I import one of my modules, which imports some of my other modules, and so on.  A few of my lowlevel modules import pyplot, and I just want to know which one of them it was (and what path of imports resulted in that module getting imported).

Comment: I think we're on the same page though because I agree that modifying `pyplot.py` seems like it would work.  Is there no way to inject a breakpoint into an external library before importing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trace Python imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332299/trace-python-imports)