# Python diagnose/log what the `import` statement does

Tags: python, import

In debugging some module issues, I would like to have insight into what exactly happens when I run `import google` (or any import modules).

- Was it loaded or did it come from cache?
- Where did it get imported from? (its not always from a file - it is possible to create a module and add it into the namespace directly)
- What loader was used?
- What about anything that was imported during the import?

Is there a way to get diagnostics on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trace Python imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332299/trace-python-imports)

Comment: @mkrieger1 its good to know for sure and is helpful, I upvoted it, but that only gives some of the info I mentioned. For example in my case in a venv with google sdk `import google` logs nothing because it is a builtin but it is not in `sys.builtin_module_names` so where is it coming from? It wasn't in the namespace previously so `import` *did* do something. More to the point, importing a module that I think *should* be on my `sys.path` is not finding it, so I want to know what it tried

Comment: digging into the specific issue more, it seems to have something to do with the `site` module which is automatically loaded. Omitting it with `-S` doesn't preload that stuff